Matrix Protocol Library for Dotnet/C#
I am searching for a Matrix Protocol library that I can use in my Dotnet/C# project.
I want to connect to the Matrix server of beeper.com (https://matrix.beeper.com) and read messages I get there. I can use a regular client like Element to connect to the beeper.com server. So that is not an issue.
First I thought XMPP and Matrix is the same, but I learned it isn't. So all the XMPP libraries don't help me as they are trying to connect via socket connections but Matrix is using HTTP(S) connections.
I found one usable project on Github (https://github.com/baking-bad/matrix-dotnet-sdk) but it seems to support no encrypted messages and also has some other bugs (I fixed them, but the main problem is the message thing). It is also not using the latest API version, so there is a risk, that the API they use may be set to deprecated state in the (near) future. There are also some other projects I found in the Matrix Documentation (https://matrix.org/ecosystem/sdks/) but most of them are not even connecting to the beeper server or are not documented, so it is almost impossible to use them. Additional many projects were not updated a long time, some even more than a decade.
Does anyone knows, if there is a Matrix library that can just do basic communication and than can be used by anyone?
